# Visual Studio 2013 Publish MVC web app - preventing folder deletion from server

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2013, publish

When publishing MVC 5 web app to server I do not want the /images/thumbs folder and its contents to be deleted. I tried many combinations but the folder contents get always wiped out. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

This is the ms deploy command I use:

```
msbuild E:\path_to_project_file\myproject.csproj /p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=test.mysite.com.pubxml /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
```

This is my test.mysite.com.pubxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
 <AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>AddCustomSkipRules</AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>

    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>\\server\websites\test.mysite.com</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <UseMsDeployExe>true</UseMsDeployExe>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="AddCustomSkipRules">
    <Message Text="Adding Custom Skip Rules" />
    <ItemGroup>

      <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipThumbs">
        <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
        <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>$(_DestinationContentPath)\\images\\thumbs\\.*</AbsolutePath>
        <Apply>Destination</Apply>
      </MsDeploySkipRules>

    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found that `<MsDeploySkipRules>` does not work when `<WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>` is set. It should be `<WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>` and MSDeploy must be configured in server.

And I followed the instructions found in http://www.leniel.net/2014/05/using-msdeploy-publish-profile-pubxml-to-create-an-empty-folder-structure-on-iis-and-skip-deleting-it-with-msdeployskiprules.html#sthash.QN1BSQN1.dpbs

and skipping the deletion of the folder I specified was accomplished.